# Does mod_pywebsocket have a non-blocking version of receive_message?

Tags: python, html, websocket, mod-pywebsocket

`request.ws_stream.receive_message()` blocks. Is there an equivalent that doesn't? Can it be used with select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the MessageReceiver class may provide asynchronous receiving and sending:

http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/source/browse/trunk/src/mod_pywebsocket/msgutil.py